# User: page giving 403

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

[Demo/Error Link](https://renegadelinewiki.com/wiki/User:Demo)

> You don't have permission to access /wiki/User:Demo on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I'm trying to setup an MediaWiki, but is running into a problem with the User pages. I though it was because of either the **.htaccess** or the SocialProfile plugin not installed.

But I've checked both, and everything should be fine.

Anyone else that have had this problem, and can help me?

Comment: *403* means you don't have permissions to access some files/urls

Comment: That's a problem with the web server, not MediaWiki or its plugins. Check the .htaccess files and other Apache config files.

Comment: Do you have anything in mind i have to look for ? The only .htaccess file i have is the one used for making short links. And i've already tried to remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be because ModSecurity was turned on by my host.
I was able to disable it though my cPanel.